# how to take input for multidimentional python list

Tags: python, list, matrix

```
#this code take input of three equation like matrix and print them
eqn_no = int(raw_input("Enter Equation no: ->"))
eqn=[] #main variable to hold data like [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
co_eff=[] #secondary variable to temporarily hold data like[1,2]
x_val=[] #hold the last term of eqn like[3,6]
for i in range(eqn_no):
    for j in range(eqn_no):
         co_eff.append(float(raw_input("Enter Co eff of a%d %d term: " %((i+1),(j+1))))) #append co-efficients piece by piece
    x_val.append(float(raw_input("Enter Co eff of b%d term: " %((i+1))))) #append last term of the equation
    eqn.append(co_eff) #appends the the equation
for i in range(eqn_no):
    co_eff=eqn[i] #takes the i number equation's co-efficient
    for j in range(eqn_no):
        print co_eff[j]
    print x_val[i]
```

This codes takes input perfectly but doesn't print correctly.
It only shows eqn[0] but outputs x_value OK. Can't find out what is the problem. I need to learn output like this because I have to access the values of the list.
For example if two equations are like x+2y=3,4x+5y=6
then I want to output like
1   2   3
4   5   6
and I also want a way to access every item of eqn[] one by one(by a loop).

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: I just edited my question. See if you have found what you  wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple regular expression that will get you started with obtaining the values from your equations:

```
>>> import re
>>> def getvalues(eqn):
    return [1 if digit == '' else int(digit) for digit in re.match(r'(\d*)x\+(\d*)y=(\d*)',eqn).groups()]

>>> getvalues('x+2y=3')
[1, 2, 3]
>>> getvalues('4x+5y=6')
[4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Your code works fine. But I wanted to give user-defined input and then store all equation in a list. Can you help me with putting value in a list after receiving input.

Answer (score 0):

this is resetting your co_eff list through every for iteration to whatever eqn[i] is equal to for that iteration:

```
for i in range(eqn_no):
    co_eff=eqn[i] #takes the i number equation's co-efficient
    for j in range(eqn_no):
        print co_eff[j]
    print x_val[i]
```

Comment: Then how should I do it? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I still am not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish unfortunately.  I was just pointing out that in your code you were reassigning your list, and I didn't think you had intended to do that.

Comment: @Martin_Lear,  I wanted i number sublist of eqn to be copied to co_eff so that i could get i number sublist of eqn by iteration. is there any other way to print every character of this nested list by a loop.